# How to bring a dead MacBook Pro back to life

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, macos

I have inherited a Mid/Late 2007 MacBook Pro from a colleague (A1226) but it doesn't work. It won't start up at all. No boot, not even the SuperDrive sound. I've tried resetting the SMC but it didn't do anything. When I connect the charger, the green light comes on, but that's the only sign of anything I see. It's also missing the battery. He doesn't remember what happened to this particular computer but the battery is broken open. Looked like some serious damage to it.

I'd like to get it working even without the battery, but I don't know what to try. I've read on here that it may be the DC in board? ifixit has a nice guide to remove the DC in board (https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Core+2+Duo+Models+A1226+and+A1260+Left+I-O+Board+Replacement/678) but I don't want to try it unless I have some evidence it may be this.

What can I try to help diagnose the source of my issue?

Comment: The battery is missing, or it is broken open?

Comment: It's broken open so I left it in his office. I may be able to get it back if it would be useful.

Comment: It would not be useful. In fact, it should be safely discarded at the battery recycling service offered by most electronic retailers. This notebook should boot normally without a battery. The power adapter may not be functional even if it lights when it is inserted. I would test with a known working adapter before you proceed to other troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I have tried other chargers with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

First, tether this MacBook Pro to a working Mac with a Firewire port. Attempt starting the MacBook Pro to Target Disk Mode. While the working Mac is on, and the MacBook Pro is off–but connected to power–and both computers are connected to each other via a Firewire cable: press the power button on the MacBook Pro and immediately press and hold the T key on its keyboard. Normally, you will begin to see a Target Disk Mode screensaver on the target Mac and its hard disk drive will mount to the filesystem of the working Mac. If neither the screensaver appears or the drive is mounted, check the System Information app on the working Mac and select Firewire from the list. Verify if there are any signs that the Firewire port is connected to a computer.

If that fails, it highly likely that the power connector and/or logic board are broken.

Comment: I really appreciate this recommendation, but I don't have a 2nd Mac with a FireWire port. My working Mac is a Late 2008 MacBook.

Comment: You could get a Thunderbolt to Firewire adapter if you know someone with a recent Mac.